# Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a error with following type definition, at L102.

[**Too long url link to read**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEEHEAUBlQMwDoAMpAdJKAzgTwK4CWANgPYA0oALgIYC21BAdtaNYwCagmUAWApgCdQAWQJYsAaz45QAYxKNKAggCM8lEgKwAobXwAeAB02U5CrKYF8AZllABeUAG9tASGElZEgEo2AXM7aoMFUOIZ8AQDkJCoAVnyylJGsdvKMFmRBoAC+KWbplJnZANy6BsYCppRhfKDQ1F587AA8+qAGlHwcdlI4JNah4f2gVrYAfA6gAMqy-PQAKjXN1UMDo1gA2voAumOl2iu1i+FTSkwA5jaTkYx4RETJAD6gkSokJER8bE8vTJ2XAh+NzwtBUgiBFmUjHOQOoAgE1BwQJi8USsMYSNKh2mZ2hABEbPMSMc+M15u19J1uqASacoZdrBN7G5yR0uuw7MD7skAPygW73UB+FkUqkcl5vD5fRi80CSz5sIUitnUyJ-PgA2W3UGCJWuVmU9mc7VgwGgPkm3XC-Wio0vSEXWUO6GgZ546idPUGsWcuEIpHm0C+ajsBREHDgeGI5psHATa3eu3ROIJJKB3zyAQtZ3nCix+NuWP7ECgHiUSiGLB+EBYADu1HOAKQBBIwCw4VkBGsBFkHpbjGAPKwKiwXwEs3sJEMlH71CIAGIsLM+PQALQo1MHGqgADy1hmcxYjhcrisIbDMlje55AWDocY4cj-uaB5X1D2bjP9-DXEYfGvt5fN+EZRjgL7LvQH6nkBF6sPcAFBjBD4gc+r6QaU2RlEYJigOqAjWA0tRoSwKrinuxGBNB57IYMfA3jSNR0hcNilFRwH8ncRDUConz0fK0qsV+sFTjOChznx7wKowglIT+BCdLQWD0cRMnUT+hgCFOggznwSkBDucSlCEIyyTIVgAI6EFY7D0XeF5PtGvTDAAcgozmcdxnzLDwYgbJEGlaZUBC6ZEuxQUJNHsLpsjKNO-b0TmqnsQYdCGLxARFp+pmgNYmj0JQCW4ucSWwaM9FOQMhzDOsJU0V0IK2aZDlgTm4XZVFBF3AVAQABS8L5kSHKFtrUrSRVXHyTH4oSxJLP1myDTUoXxqwGIAJSuhx9y1T+9D6LAXTnLw9GWgIO0yLQTAHdCx0BKdGG6NiviWQQ1nQJp4SVDgzl0LpzR2KRdgGbETKURsADSuGMKAFXYNs1quCWkNiPy3BcHFYlEG4ribOD2x+SJs4PNsI3igRRCjoGkMI0jpbUHYHXUF1oAAG5zngfDY7j+ORIzXXDYDW1EJtOabadm38YqzwZpo2ZFRQeCMBIjAkLWjATHy1P8nwLOCNo2QbLDWDbPs5Q4diwOTDLWb-fL0wQe+pvYZUtG7nEJL-aTQNxBQz1WU071TgDhrUkbTJuE4oCrhFP4bNAUMw9IwzG8pDse5s0C7DkoAAGQR1HMcyHHCd+69AcfcbATEencdZ7keeuJH0fZcXTCIS9b0fdp32-Vg-1jPD9uHjXmcTCUj3bu58ECAAqhwNhME0zSGF7Q9vhQ8zh64hh+QKXE8XwAsh+KSgc9jPLbwTGPMMTq+n5zriP3yPXks8e+bYrHWL+wa3Y64vWvyFr-R+AQd7RGvnOI+PoqACDPo-Vwz9AGfwXn+H+f8AjzGLGAMsFYqw1hoF4Egut8KkFrEgeQtBgCWV0qJdIwAACsAAWAAnAgAAHAARkYRw4AhwlyxUoKuNIxDBGK37KuDQq48KjkSP2bQJZIB8FMNI1M-YcqaVoKAMRChQBbnCKAOe-YiQAElFCCBkbQ5oM9QY9RnqvWMgYeoSACDPDa9gJgsxIAQTgd0daCA2oLHqTiAhMGsLqYxbiPFeJ-oGYxQptbEKwaWcslZqzAHOPJHgeAVDkJIJQy64heiriiizYABTJDSGAIYTiwBOGMMYfOdgYhZB4HEP2AA+gIAA7Gw+hAAmNhXT6H9PkWAIkoBLimG0YwCgtZaitNqAAAwAGLvHsRiQMAAJEglxmirJICtP8xDFl6NqIYhQ1clgkWPnYQuq0cAbG2BQAAGqvCijhqAbFOlnRwrzBYOMmmnJYzzDl+LOqciAoFzmMDJKDRM1IAWQufJveJRzBDFF0XoZ2VRtyXPCASawy83kOy3mAoaJNBZcgeIGd+1oyVLQpTc34ZjNQ0pBKaPU9LwhQKTKdLU7KrRuC5YfRl0DIg5llD1bGYD6q0B5dSO5OZHnmj-jK7UoUvkCoECTBGl9Ii5QEPleV4peYej4BIggtBD6BlFgEEs7pOiAGsGQAmgyAGiGQA+P-ur-jmNwG06V+XJavV4klpSykltDf1i1uWiqTBuNEjjpV+VGManoSdKo1GqjYOwfJ6iNBaGA5NWdfHENdIm-yXcgohRjdSVyjAp77y8sDDWbtYgezAQFT6OksChQoLW+tnlSQFr4B3Joy1NU6m1aCktjwy1XmsCmxCakULRmIs26FeLB1+TnctXOdQ4QzjnFYxgRiSCmM6FoVRCgj39g3cvLdGI9zLTGFO3UM7H5gLnEQR91bxR2WQs1cCh413HoUCYsxF7ZFXvXUC8Id7Iifu-c+1FYLfWcoDQyoNfpESSrLfJFc3af1A33A7BN8CwF4cUhq+DD752EcXcBADq7AzQeHksPtHkD5wYowR+9OBENjGVbq8jCkePRD-N+1ef7HygUA2+ZtzVoXXouTB0k7H7gDq4yJqjCh-y0efQWMjfluNUYQ7RyTTUZNMb5NCsD56LH9iU4wW9amG2brVFpnmpmn0CZ1X-NFAhsZ+twx51eLmNNWbXgsGoBLNP4bHb5x+sZHmocjTpiTgspPLrAhFljb420E3E3pvUmUsUVBxfo29K9BZMccPWncs957dlQcvCgG6YuGGfaUIAA)

TypeScript 4.6.2 sais...

```
(property) Schema.items?: Schema | undefined
Type 'Schema & p["items"]' does not satisfy the constraint 'Schema'.
  Types of property 'required' are incompatible.
    Type '(readonly (keyof NonNullable<(Schema & p["items"])["properties"]>)[] & readonly (keyof NonNullable<p["items"]["properties"]>)[]) | undefined' is not assignable to type 'readonly string[] | undefined'.
      Type 'readonly (keyof NonNullable<(Schema & p["items"])["properties"]>)[] & readonly (keyof NonNullable<p["items"]["properties"]>)[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly string[] | undefined'.
        Type 'readonly (keyof NonNullable<(Schema & p["items"])["properties"]>)[] & readonly (keyof NonNullable<p["items"]["properties"]>)[]' is not assignable to type 'readonly string[]'.
          The types returned by 'concat(...)' are incompatible between these types.
            Type '(keyof NonNullable<(Schema & p["items"])["properties"]>)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
              Type 'keyof NonNullable<(Schema & p["items"])["properties"]>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'string'.
                  Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2344)
```

If I change L34, Schema interface definition, from

```
    readonly required?: ReadonlyArray<keyof NonNullable<this['properties']>>;
```

to

```
    readonly required?: ReadonlyArray<keyof NonNullable<Schema['properties']>>;
```

that removes the error, but I want to use `this`.

Is there any way to clear errors while using `this`?

Comment: Why would you use `this` in an interface?

Comment: @kellys Because that is how I would like to define it. But now that you say so, I feel there is no need to be stubborn about using `this`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Extract.

```
    readonly required?: ReadonlyArray<Extract<keyof NonNullable<this['properties']>, string>>;
```

https://zenn.dev/jiftechnify/scraps/6f0bdab4be0a8f